# Alternate between implementation in dependency injection

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have a restful api of a b2c store and now I need to implement it for a b2b store using the same endpoints, everything works different in both types so the implementation is different. Right now one exemplo of a endpoint would be like this:

---

```
use App\Service\Calculator;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    private $calculator;

    public function __construct(Request $request, Calculator $calculator)
    {
        parent::__construct($request);
        $this->calculator = $calculator
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->calculator->calculate();
        return response()->json(['ok'], 200);
    }
```

### }

So I thought in inject an interface and let the provider decide which implementation use. Like this:

---

```
namespace App\Service;

interface CalculatorInterface
{
    public function calculate();
}
```

---

```
namespace App\Service;

class Service1 implements CalculatorInterface
{
    public function calculate() { /** */ }
}
```

---

```
namespace App\Service;

class Service2 implements CalculatorInterface
{
    public function calculate() { /** */ }
}
```

---

```
use App\Service\CalculatorInterface;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    private $calculator;

    public function __construct(Request $request, CalculatorInterface $calculator)
    {
        parent::__construct($request);
        $this->calculator = $calculator
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->calculator->calculate();
        return response()->json(['ok'], 200);
    }
}
```

To decide which type use (b2b or b2c) I need the user logged which I can't get when registering a provider. I could decide in the controller which implementation user, but I have many endpoint and would have to do that manually in all of them.
So what I need is alternate between the implementation in the dependency injection based on the user.
Maybe pass a parameter in the header of the request and so in the provide I check that?

Comment: Using a factory class which gets the service based on user might be helpful IMHO. I'm not an expert of design patterns, but this thought came to my mind first.

Comment: You can use dyamic app binding basedon your case to set which implementation of interface should be injected. See if this helps : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549640/how-to-register-and-resolve-multiple-application-life-time-scope-objects-with-sa/54549786#54549786.